# Clang: How to see contents of pcm-file - clang precompiled module

Tags: swift, clang, swift-package-manager

I am troubleshooting Swift build compile issues and want to see all C definitions inside pcm file (i.e. `/.../sample-package/.build/aarch64-unknown-linux-android/debug/ModuleCache/3H5CVD7WO3N6R/SwiftGlibc-2G37BC3YW3KOQ.pcm`).

How to do it? Is the any clang or llvm tool which can dump all symbols defined on C language side and included into precompiled clang module?

Answer (score 2):

With Swift you can use:

```
swiftc -dump-pcm path/to/foo.pcm -target something ...
```

Where you do have to pass at least some of the flags you used to compile the module. In my testing you at least need `-target` and `-sdk` to be correct.

If you have a `pcm` generated by clang, you can use:

```
clang -module-file-info path/to/foo.pcm
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the command line tool *strings*

```
strings file.pcm
```